# Why does cloning a private git repository via Drush make file fail using SSH authentication?

Tags: version-control, drush

I have multiple private git accounts set up with SSH system's keychain authentication for each git repo.

It works to clone private git repos from command line:

```
git clone git@git_ssh_alias:git-account/some_repo.git
```

The `git_ssh_alias` is the alias name declared in `.ssh/config` file that specifies the SSH key that should be used.

However, this same clone doesn't work when running from make file via Drush script as following.

#### From Make file:

```
projects[theme_name][type] = "theme"
projects[theme_name][version] = 7.x-1.0
projects[theme_name][download][type] = "git"
projects[theme_name][download][url] = "git@git_ssh_alias:git-account/some_repo.git"
projects[theme_name][download][branch] = "master"
```

#### From Drush script:

```
drush_invoke_process('@self', 'make', array($make_file), $options)
```

where `$make_file` is a path to a make file and options are:

```
$options = array();
$options['no-core'] = TRUE;
$options['yes'] = TRUE;
$options['contrib-destination'] = 'sites/all';
```

**My question**: How to clone private git repo with local ssh keychain authentication enabled?

Comment: I would have expected it to work like you describe... You could try the `gitcloneparams` option.

Comment: Could it be, you are drush as a _different_ user -- not as the one you use to test `git` from command line?

Comment: Verify you're using the right RSA keys by `ssh-add -l`. If you've multiple keys, use only one.

Answer (score 0):

Using modules and not theme_name may resolve this.

```
projects[modules][type] = modules
projects[modules][download][type] = git
projects[modules][download][url] = git@bitbucket.org:company/repo.git
projects[modules][download][branch] = master
```

Here are a couple of useful links:

https://groups.drupal.org/node/194303#comment-918073
http://www.systemseed.com/blog/drush-make-private-git-repository-github